# How to rebind same viewmodel in knockout

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I want to rebind same model with new data or you can say after calling ajax I want to update the model with totaly new data.

```
function returnData(url,data,type){
    $.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {

    if(type == "search")
    {
    ko.applyBindings(new SearchViewModel(returnedData,"#searchbox",url,data),$("#searchbox")[0]);   
    }
});
}
```

this is the code which call ajax for data and when the new data recived it binds it to the model.
The first time is not the problem but next time it doubles the same data.

```
returnData(doamin+"/1.0/search",{userid:"12033914132",keyword:""},"search");
```

I want to call the same function when ever I input a new search word.

I know that we can use observable to update data, but I want to clear the old bindings and add new one

```
function SearchViewModel(data,id,url,userdata) {
    var self = this;
    // Editable data

    var ParsedData = JSON.parse(data);

    self.Contacts = ko.observableArray(ParsedData.Contacts);
    self.Sms = ko.observableArray(ParsedData.Sms);
    self.Calendar = ko.observableArray(ParsedData.Calendar);
    self.Logs = ko.observableArray(ParsedData.Logs);
    self.Total = ko.toJS(self.Contacts).length+ko.toJS(self.Sms).length+ko.toJS(self.Calendar).length;
    self.ContactsCount = ko.toJS(self.Contacts).length;
    self.SmsCount = ko.toJS(self.Sms).length;
    self.CalendarCount = ko.toJS(self.Calendar).length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd only apply bindings once, then use the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to update the existing view model:

```
function SearchViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // Editable data

    self.Contacts = ko.observableArray();
    self.Sms = ko.observableArray();
    self.Calendar = ko.observableArray();
    self.Logs = ko.observableArray();
    self.Total = ko.toJS(self.Contacts).length+ko.toJS(self.Sms).length+ko.toJS(self.Calendar).length;
    self.ContactsCount = ko.toJS(self.Contacts).length;
    self.SmsCount = ko.toJS(self.Sms).length;
    self.CalendarCount = ko.toJS(self.Calendar).length;    
}
```

You will need to change your count properties to [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html), but everything else should be mapped over by the mapping plugin:

```
var searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();

function returnData(url,data,type){
    $.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {

    if(type == "search")
    {
      searchViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(returnedData);
    }
});
}
ko.applyBindings(new SearchViewModel(returnedData,"#searchbox",url,data),$("#searchbox")[0]);
```

Comment: Try that update. If it still doesn't work, then you're going to need to expand on what isn't working.

Comment: i think it is not working because of this var `searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();` it is not able to make an object of this class.i am still asking is there any thing without using mapping

Comment: Updated the view model for you, you will have to change the count properties to computed observables, follow the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can store you SearchViewModel in an observable. With that you can update your SearchViewModel without needing any mapping or rebinding.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.searchViewModel = ko.observable();
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#searchbox")[0]); 

function returnData(url,data,type){
    $.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {

    if(type == "search")
    {
    // ko.applyBindings(new SearchViewModel(returnedData,"#searchbox",url,data),$("#searchbox")[0]);   
       viewModel.searchViewModel(new SearchViewModel(returnedData,"#searchbox",url,data));
    }
});
}
```

View:

```
<div id="#searchbox" data-bind="if: searchViewModel()">
    <div data-bind="with: searchViewModel()">
       ... your markup
    </div>    
</div>
```